# How to display data on datatables using laravel 5?

Tags: php, json, datatable, laravel-5, datatables

I am using laravel 5 and I want to show field in jenis_surat column in database to my table using datatables. I want to using JSON, do you know how to show the number depends on the entries of the data. 
here is my controller (It's just shows data in jenis_surat):

```
public function jenissurat()
{return view('jenissurat');}

  public function datajenissurat()
{
    $jenissurat = new JenisSurat();
    $jenissurats = $jenissurat->select('jenis_surat')->get();   
    return $jenissurats;
}
```

And how to display it on datatables? example:
 No. Jenis Surat. .Action
1.   .   .A    .     .    .  .  .   .   .  .  . Edit | Delete
2.   .   .B    .     .    .  .  .   .   .  .  . Edit | Delete
3.   .   .F    .     .    .  .  .   .   .  .  . Edit | Delete

```
<table id="jenissurat" class="table table-bordered table-striped" cellspacing="0" widht="100%">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th width="4%">No.</th>
              <th width="80%">Jenis Surat</th>
              <th width="16%">Action</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
        </table>
        <script type="text/javascript">

          $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#publish').DataTable({
              'columns' : [
                {'data' : 'jenis_surat'}
              ]
            });
          });

        </script>
```

Here is my route:

```
Route::get('/jenissurat', [
'uses' => 'SuratController@jenissurat',
'as' => 'jenissurat'
]); Route::get('/datajenissurat', [
'uses' => 'SuratController@datajenissurat',
'as' => 'datajenissurat'
]);here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, I am not sure this is a best solution from the performance point of view.

```
public function jenissurat()
 {
    $returnValue = $this->datajenissurat();
    return view('jenissurat', compact('returnValue'));
 }

 public function datajenissurat()
 {
    $jenissurat = new JenisSurat();
    DB::statement(DB::raw('set @rownum=0'));

    $jenissurats = $jenissurat->select([DB::raw('@rownum  := @rownum  + 1 AS rownum'), 'jenis_surat'])->get();   
    return $jenissurats;
 }
```

And regarding to the Datatables you can add something like this.

```
  <script>

    $(function() {

       var oTable = $('#publish').DataTable({
           bProcessing    : true,
           serverSide     : true,
           /* sDom           : 'p', */
           dom            : 'Bfrtip',
           ajax: {
           url: '{!! route("datajenissurat") !!}',
           data: function (d) {

           }
        },        
      columns: [
        { data: 'rownum', name: 'rownum' ,orderable: false, searchable:  false },
        { data: 'jenis_surat', name: 'jenis_surat' },
        { data: 'action', name: 'action', orderable: false, searchable:  false }
        ]
     });
   });
  </script>
```

I see a edit/delete column that can be used by the action column. So, the ajax call to your controller function `datajenissurat()` will return a json array, which can be parsed using the datatable script.

Comment: I've got an error "Class 'App\Http\Controllers\DB' not found"

Comment: add 'Use DB; ` at top of your controller OR use \DB in your query.

Comment: yeah it works, thanks. And do you know how to display the json data on the datatables?

Comment: Can you show the code you have done so far, with integrating datatables

Comment: <table id="publish" class="table table-bordered table-striped" cellspacing="0" widht="100%">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>No.</th>
                  <th>Publish</th>
                  <th>Action</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
            </table>
            <script type="text/javascript">

              $(document).ready(function(){
                $('#publish').DataTable({
                  'columns' : [
                    {'data' : 'publish'}
                  ]
                });
              });
            </script>

Comment: what is the meaning of table_previous_link and jobs-table_previous on "var table_previous_link = '#jobs-table_previous';" should I just write it like that?

Comment: just ignore that. I copied it from my file. I will update the answer.

Comment: hmm I don't know but it's still not working. there's no data shows in the table. about url, I try to change  url: '{!! route("datajenissurat") !!}' and url: '{!! route("jenissurat") !!}' but it won't work

Comment: do u have a route name defined as datajenissurat or jenissurat. In my example I have defined a named route. if you dont have one simple call the url  which will hit the function that fetch from database. when using ajax call you need not pass anything via view.

Comment: Updated my answer. can you check whether there is an ajax call and can you just copy paste the json response here.

Comment: this is my json: [{"no":1,"jenis_surat":"Memorandum"},{"no":2,"jenis_surat":"Prosedur Mutu"},{"no":3,"jenis_surat":"Surat Edaran"},{"no":4,"jenis_surat":"Surat Keputusan"}]

Comment: just noticed your table id is `jenissurat`? then you should give that name in `var oTable = $('#jenissurat').DataTable({` replacing `publish`

Comment: Any error? JS or PHP. I believe that you have your datatable JS, jquery etc are loaded and running properly.

Comment: nothing error. it's ok if we can't find the solution. I can use foreach for that. You have helping me a lot ;)

Comment: And, I am here for that. :-) There are pretty good packages like Yajra which works well with serverside stuff and datatables. Try using it.

Comment: a final try, just replace `action` with `jenis_surat` in column section of your js and pls let me know the result

Answer (score 0):

```
public function datajenissurat()
{
    $jenissurats = $jenissurat->select('jenis_surat')->get();   
    return view('view.show', compact('jenissurats '));
}
```

and also make view

Comment: it's not working. I'm type the link for show the json but got an error.  My function was already working but I want to show the number column no, which is not in database.